# What does a <- a || b mean in pseudocode?

Tags: data-structures, artificial-intelligence, pseudocode

I am trying to learn about the GADDAG data structure, developed by Steven A. Gordon. While I was reading the document [here](http://ericsink.com/downloads/faster-scrabble-gordon.pdf), I came across the following pseudocode example:

```
If pos <= 0 THEN {moving left:}
    word <- L || word
...
```

I was unable to find what this means by searching around and I was wondering what it means.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From context, this appears to be string concatenation. The author mentions this in the paragraphs leading into the pseudocode:

> In the GoOn procedure, the direction determines which side of the current word to concatenate the current letter to

This is also supported by the directionality implied in the pseudocode. If the position is below zero (that is, you're before the start of the word), you prepend the new letter to the front. If the position is greater than zero (that is, you're past the start of the word), you append the new letter to the end.

Apparently || is [used in some languages to denote string concatenation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(strings)#Concatenation), including PL/1 and SQL.